# cannot use `OUTER` as label name for loop control in Raku

Tags: raku

If I use `OUTA` as a label name it works, but `OUTER` doesn't:

```
OUTA:  say OUTA.^name;  # Label
OUTER: say OUTER.^name; # OUTER
```

Thus:

```
OUTA:  loop { last OUTA  } # works
OUTER: loop { last OUTER } # fails (see below)
```

---

It is strange that `OUTER` cannot be used as a label name for loop control in Raku. For example,

```
OUTER:
loop {
    loop { state $c = 0; say $c++; last OUTER if $c > 2 }

}
```

The output and the error message is as follow:

```
0
1
2
Cannot resolve caller last(OUTER:U); none of these signatures matches:
    ( --> Nil)
    (Label:D $x --> Nil)
  in block  at <unknown file> line 1
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
  in any <main> at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rakudo-star/2024.03/bin/../share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
  in any <entry> at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rakudo-star/2024.03/bin/../share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm line 1
```

Changing `OUTER` to `OUT`, `OUTE`, `OUTA`, etc. will work just fine. Is `OUTER` a type name which cannot be used as a label name? I have searched for it but cannot find any mention of `OUTER` in docs.raku.org.

Comment: It's a bug. [`OUTER` is the name of a "pseudo package"](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#:~:text=OUTER,outer%20lexical%20scope) (which I don't think is quite a type, at least not at the users' run-time level, but is presumably very closely related at the compilation level). In a 2022 Rakudo some (ordinary) type names (eg `Int`) cause a compile time error during construction of the label, other types are accepted and work as labels (eg `Date`), and pseudo-packages I tried are accepted as labels but fail to work.

Comment: I looked for but did not find a matching bug in the old or new Rakudo issue trackers. If you've switched RakuAST on in a reasonably up-to-date Rakudo, and it's not yet been fixed as part of that work, I'd imagine filing an issue about this may gain you kudos, and filing a PR fixing it will gain you that plus bathe you in love. I imagine the right solution would be making pseudo-packages work (like, eg, `Date` does).